# How can I add navbar band logo at center using react bootstrap in react js

Tags: reactjs

How to add <Navbar.Brand href="#home"> logo at center using react-bootstrap. Please find the below code I wrote.
Please help with this.

```
import React from 'react'
// import styles from './header.module.css'
// import { HomenetLink } from '../theme/components/Hyperlink'
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Navheader from './NavHeader'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

const Header = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar expand="lg">
      <Navheader/>
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><img
                id="homenetlogo"
                src="../.././images/homemain.png"
                alt="HomeNet"
                width="165px"
                height="30px;"
              /></Navbar.Brand>
   <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="ml-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="javascript:void(0);" className="coverage-activate" data-activates="coverage">{t('header.coverage')}</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="http://homenet_local/kundeservice" data-collapsible="coverage" >{t('header.customerService')}</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/minside/" data-collapsible="coverage" >{t('header.myPage')}</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add a class as below and add css

```
.brand-center {justify-content: "center"}

 <Navbar.Brand href="#home" className="brand-center"><img
                id="homenetlogo"
                src="../.././images/homemain.png"
                alt="HomeNet"
                width="165px"
                height="30px;"
              /></Navbar.Brand>
```